# Could not find virtualization option in Bios setting

Tags: virtualization, bios

[image]

Not able to find the virtualization option. Please help.

Comment: Let me add that your questions belongs to http://serverfault.com as this website is for programming questions, not computer administration and configuring.

Answer (score 0):

What processor does your system have? Have you checked with [ARK](http://ark.intel.com) that it actually has Intel VT-x?

The virtualization knob is situated in the "Security" tab most of the time.